# API 22 Camera by Intent Issue

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm developing an android app currently with the min sdk being 19, and trying to support all the way up till 26. This week I've added a camera feature to an activity and I'm finding it ridiculously challenging to debug this.

Basically the user clicks the camera icon, and it starts the android camera through an intent, user takes the picture, it gets saved, then added to the slider gallery they were viewing before launching the camera intent.

So I finally got it working on API 19, 21, 23, 24, 25 and 26... The only API that is giving me an issue is 22 and I really cannot figure out why. When I click the camera icon, it launches the intent, the camera loads to a white screen, and the app crashes. The kicker is this, I just tried it and it worked, thats twice now that the app successfully took the picture, saved it and did not crash.

After it worked, i tried it again and I got this:

> 09-09 17:19:22.381 6163-6163/com.android.camera E/Camera: Error 100
>   09-09 17:19:22.381 6163-6163/com.android.camera E/CameraErrorCallback: Got >camera error callback. error=100
>   09-09 17:19:22.381 6163-6163/com.android.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL >EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: >com.android.camera, PID: 6163
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Media server died.
> >                                                                          at >com.android.camera.CameraErrorCallback.onError(CameraErrorCallback.java:31)
> >                                                                          at >android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1148)
> >                                                                          at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> >                                                                          at >android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> >                                                                          at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
> >                                                                          at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                          at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

And after trying it a bit later I got yet again, a different error..

> 09-09 17:32:22.185 1530-1611/system_process E/AudioService: Media server died.
>   09-09 17:32:22.191 4072-4072/com.android.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL >EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: >com.android.camera, PID: 4072
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
> >                                                                          at >android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
> >                                                                          at >android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1888)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.camera.Camera.initializeZoom(Camera.java:489)
> >                                                                         at >com.android.camera.Camera.initializeFirstTime(Camera.java:392)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.camera.Camera.access$600(Camera.java:87)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.camera.Camera$MainHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:290)
> >                                                                          at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> >                                                                          at >android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> >                                                                          at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
> >                                                                          at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                          at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> >                                                                          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Here is my code revolving around calling the camera function/activity:

Setting camera icon onclick listener:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() >
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(CameraUtility.dispatchTakePictureIntent(getApplicationContext(), mushroomFolder), 1);
                return;
            }
        });
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The on activity for result just adds the last taken photo to the gallery and is not even reached so I wont bother including it.

And heres the code for my CameraUtility:

```
class CameraUtility extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH;
public static String PHOTO_DIRECTORY;

public static void setPhotoDirectory(Context c) {
    PHOTO_DIRECTORY = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/MyTrackerPhotos/";
}

public static Intent dispatchTakePictureIntent(Context c, String name) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String path = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/MyTrackerPhotos/" + name + "/" + name + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri outputFileUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)           
        outputFileUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(c,
        "com.tracker.mushroom.fileprovider", file);
    else
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH = file.getPath();
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    return intent;
}

public static String getCurrentPhotoPath() {
    return CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH;
}

public static File[] getImageFiles(Context c, String mushroomFolder) throws IOException {
    String filePath = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/MyTrackerPhotos/" + mushroomFolder;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.mkdirs();
    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setWritable(true);
    return file.listFiles();
    }
}
```

So I'm not really sure if its an issue of my code, or if its the emulator or if its something else I don't even know about, because if every other API is working, I cant help but just scratch my head. I know the getParameters() error is related to the Camera class, but I am not even using it so I'm not sure why it even triggers that error. All and any input is welcome and much appreciated.

Comment: That isn't an API related issues, it is the Camera app you're calling into crashing. Are you trying this on a API 22 emulator?

Comment: If you work with a real device, it could simply be a device-specific problem. I have encountered quite a few devices that had weird camera problems. Furthermore, it could also be a problem with the default camera app on that device. The owner can set up any app that manifests support for the Camera intents to handle them, instead of the system camera app. And even system camera app may be buggy on a less-polished device.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, api 22 emulator, different phones. Are you trying to say their is an issue with the default camera app provided on the emulator?  Because that would make a lot of sense.

Comment: @AlexCohn I wish I had a physical api 22 device, but all my tests, save the last 3 robo tests I did were on emulator. 1 robo test was a virtual Nexus 7 api 22, and the other were physical devices, nexus 4 and 5 api 22 both. All 3 passed, all 3 successfully launched the activity.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I did some further testing and I think I am at the point where I am going to blame this on the emulator/android studio. I ran 3 firebase robo tests, all on api 22 and different phone models.

Each one of these continually opened and closed the camera activity just fine, unfortunately the tests never actually took a picture, but the crash was happening before that anyway.

If I could test this out my self on a physical device that has API 22, and it works, I'd know for sure its an emulator/android issue. At this point I don't even feel its worth investing time to try and debug this especially after the robo tests. Hope someone finds this useful and saves some time chasing after some mutating ghost error, lol.

EDIT:
 Would like to add as a final note.. I downloaded api 22 x86, installed it and made a new emulator. No more problems. I was using api 22 x86_64, and for some reason it just does not like to work on that version. Cheers to those who commented, you guys were pretty bang on.